# Hiding passwords in python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, python-keyring

I have a Python application that has a file containing several hardcoded databases credentials. I have to find a way to hide these information, because keeping usernames and passwords in the code is insecure.
I came across Keyring library which could be an alternative, but it also allows an unauthorized developer to print passwords throw the get_password method.
Does anyone have any tips for hiding or encrypting passwords in Python, preventing them from printing?

Comment: How should that work? The decrypted password should be available in your code (for authentication) but not available (for printing) at the same time.

Comment: @KlausD. Not actually. What really matters is to hide those passwords. Whether with encryption or otherwise. I don't want anyone who opens the script to be able to access the passwords. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe my response was too complex. I'll shorten it to: not possible. What is possible is to increase the time needed to retrieve the credentials to maybe a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting your passwords into a `.env` file and adding it to your `.gitignore`.

Have a look at this write up, it might help you with keeping credentials safe.

https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5